# If only he had cycled

Tags: verbs, conjugation

To the question,

> How did you get here?

the response was,

> I bike rode.

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: why do *you* think it is incorrect?

Comment: @GEdgar because `bike` already includes riding so why `rode` is there!!!

Comment: Hello Terencio, and Welcome to EL&U. You might want to visit English Language Learners; you can find it [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It is very helpful in answering basic questions.

Comment: In order to use _bike_ as a verb, you need to give it a past tense ending. I **biked.** That is acceptable, but informal. You can use _cycled_ that way as well. You might also say, _I **rode** my bike_, where bike is a noun, and rode is the verb.

Comment: Is it possible to say: I car drove; I truck drove; I ship sailed etc.? *Bike, car, and ship* are nouns not verbs. Instead *you drove a car*; *you [rode](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ride) a bike* and *you sailed on a ship*.

Comment: So answering the question, "How do you get to work?", one can't answer "I bike."? Or if I were a trucker, can one not truck? Or if a shipper, ship?

Comment: Do I not say, "I bike ride to work."?

Comment: Is the statement, "I bike ride to work everyday." wrong?

Comment: How is it wrong, grammatically?

Comment: Word order. We don't normally use _subject+object+verb_ in a simple English sentence.

Comment: Terencio, the response is extremely awkward and unnatural.

Comment: You can say whatever you like, people will probably understand or get the gist of  "I truck over the highway" but I've never heard a native speaker say: *I bike ride to work*. That is not English. The Italian equivalent would be:  "sono andata in bicicletta" = *I'm went in bicycle*.  That last sentence is NOT English either; different languages, different rules.

Comment: Now, see, I'm new to this site, and as a native New Yorker, I certainly don't need to checkout the 'English Language Learners' (one hopes), but I DID want to see if the answers I got here would be accurate. I happen to say 'I bike rode' frequently, and have been told it was wrong, quite often. However, no-one has ever been able to tell me why. As a lover of the language but with only a high school education, I could see no reason why it wouldn't be correct. So far, I still have seen no reason why it wouldn't be correct. Lots of responses. No reasons.

Comment: @Terencio: I've retracted my closevote, since I now realise you were specifically asking ***why*** people tend say your usage is "incorrect" (as opposed to just "what do other people ***think*** about it). FWIW I'm in complete agreement with what Colin posted - but as you say, "No reasons". All I can add is that [*we gut sense*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22we+gut+sense%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) there's something "not quite right" about using nouns as "prefixed adverbs" (but we still do it sometimes! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly understandable and grammatical, but not something that a native speaker would say. Compound verbs with an embedded object noun do exist, but they tend to occur in technical writing and not in everyday speech.

Comment: Finallly, an answer.  "I bike rode" is not ungrammatical or incorrect.  But it is unusual.  Since "I biked" or "I rode my bike" are more common, if you use one of these it will not show that you are a non-native speaker.  But what's wrong with showing you are a non-native speaker?

Comment: @GEdgar How can you say that is a grammatical sentence?  Unusual, yes, so unusual in fact there is not one instance on Google books which lists the phrase, there's plenty of evidence for the latter though  [I bike rode vs. I rode a bike](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+bike+rode%2CI+rode+a+bike&year_start=1940&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20rode%20a%20bike%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Mari-Lou: It's "grammatical" in that English allows nouns to be used adverbially/adjectivally (as in [*I **road hiked** up through the hills*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+road+hiked%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)). We also allow nouns to be used as verbs ([*I **biked** through the hills*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+biked+through+the+hills%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)). But *idiomatically* we're not consistent, so we don't ***car** through the hills*, even though in principle it would be "grammatical".

Comment: @FumbleFingers   If the OP's phrase had been "I biked to work." That would have sounded OK; "road hiked up through..." to me is very weird but *hike* is a verb so my brain ignores the word order and makes sense of the expression. I object to the verb, RODE, immediately following the noun **bike**. There is no "ed"/"ing" ending on the word bike. And I'd argued "**we hiked up** the road through the hills" would sound better too.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: The fact that you like one form better doesn't in and of itself make a different form "ungrammmatical". Nor is it relevant that many people would include a hyphen in *"I pistol whipped him"*, or collapse two words into one in *"She lap danced for him"*. My point is "grammatical" is a slippery concept when it comes to using nouns in such ways.

Comment: So do the naysayers have a problem with, "I bike ride to work."?

Comment: @Terencio: Colin's answer sums up the situation very succinctly. Most people *don't like* your usage, simply because it's not something they would say themselves. And clearly some people feel it must therefore be "ungrammatical" (even though strictly speaking it's not). So if you don't mind people thinking your [ideolect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiolect) is at the very least "unusual" (or mistakenly thinking it's "inherently incorrect"), just carry on. If you want to sound like everyone else, get used to using ***to bike*** as a verb, and forget about ***to ride*** in this context.